# Is there a proof that Encrypting and then Decrypting any data using AES 256 will result in the same data?

Tags: algorithms, prime-numbers, computer-science, proof-verification

I use AES quite often at work (I'm a software programmer) and I trust that it "works" without understanding the maths behind it. It's a black box to me.

Does a mathematical proof exist that AES 256 encryption works for any data?

I.e. Is it guaranteed that there is no "weird pattern of plain text" (input data) which when encrypted and then decrypted yields the wrong result?

Comment: Yes, there is a proof.

Comment: @Nik. I don't believe you :) . How would I find it (please)?

Comment: Is my conceptual understanding that encryption is a "function" which maps any discrete number onto another discrete number, and that mapping is defined by the key correct? So long as a number on the left maps to just one number on the right, and vice versa, then it's reversible. Eg, for a (3 bit number space) a mapping might be: 0 -> 4, 1 -> 1, 2 -> 5, 3 -> 0, 4-> 3, 5 -> 2.

Comment: Is mapping where the info comes from or how the seeker got there?

Comment: A "real" proof is not really needed. If you look at how AES works you will see that it is just a composition of very simple operations, which are trivially invertible. (Note that by "trivially invertible", I mean that it is trivial to invert each single operation, and thus to see that their composition must be invertible as well. Of course it is not trivial to invert the whole thing, that's the point.)